# discord.py get member object by id

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, bots

I want to do something with my discord bot where it can get members by their ids, so if I had an example id 1234, I would do something like:

```
user = # where the way to get the user would be
# then...
userid = user.id # same atts and funcs like in message.author
```

I am using client:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `user = client.get_member(user.id)`.

Comment: ok! u sure this works?

Comment: It'll work if your bot's cache has the member. Otherwise, it would be better to use [`await client.fetch_user(id)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=fetch%20user#discord.Client.fetch_user) instead

Comment: Whats the difference between fetch_user and get_member?

Comment: As @Bagle explained, get_member works if the bot's cache already has the member. However, if it doesn't, then you need to use coroutines: `await client.fetch_user(id)`.

Comment: how do i store the member in the cache